# How do I play or pause a video in Exoplayer when using with the ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, exoplayer

I'm trying to use **Exoplayer** inside the **ViewPager**. It will play only when I open it by clicking on the thumbnail which I'm using to display the videos. But it won't play when I reach the page by Scrolling.

I tried calling ***`seekTo(0, 0)`*** & ***`playWhenReady = true`*** inside ***onPageSelected()*** and ***`playWhenReady = false`*** inside the ***onScrolled()*** methods of the VPAdapter using the Lambdas but didn't work.

Here is the Adapter I'm using for the viewPager.

```
class MediaVPAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    @LayoutRes val layoutRes: Int,
    val medias: List<MediaFiles> = listOf()
) : PagerAdapter() {

    private var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, o: Any): Boolean {
        return view == o
    }

    override fun getCount() = medias.size

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutRes, container, false).apply {
            if (medias.isNotEmpty()) {
                when (medias[position].mediaType) {
                    MediaType.PHOTO -> {
                        // Display the Image
                    }
                    MediaType.VIDEO -> {

                        ssImageView.makeInvisible(true)
                        exoPlayerView.makeVisible()
                        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                            DefaultRenderersFactory(context),
                            DefaultTrackSelector(),
                            DefaultLoadControl()
                        )
                        if (medias[position].uri != null)
                            initPlayer(this, medias[position].uri!!)

                    }
                    null -> {

                    }
                }
            }

            container.addView(this, 0)
        }
    }

    private fun initPlayer(view: View, uri: Uri) {
        Timber.i("initPlayer: uri: $uri")
        with(view) {
            player!!.let {
                exoPlayerView.player = it

                it.prepare(buildMediaSource(uri), true, false)

                it.playWhenReady = false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun buildMediaSource(uri: Uri) = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(
        DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, context.getString(R.string.app_name)))
    )
        .setExtractorsFactory(DefaultExtractorsFactory())
        .createMediaSource(uri)


    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, obj: Any) {
        releasePlayer()
    }

    private fun releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            playWhenReady = false
            player!!.release()
            player = null
        }
    }
}

val mediaAdapter = MediaVPAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.fragment_media,
            true,
            medias?.toList() ?: listOf()
        )
        vpMedia.adapter = mediaAdapter
        vpMedia.currentItem = position ?: 0
        vpMedia.offscreenPageLimit = 1
```

If I click on a Video, the selected Video could be played but when I scroll to some other item, none of them were playing. When I try to toggle the Play/Pause button, only the button was toggling.

Answer (score 0):

As far i can see you you code misses the *setPlayWhenReady* listener.
You should fix it by adding ***`it.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady)`*** in the ***initPlayer*** method.